Quartz.net job store Redis
I can get it to store the jobs in the redis, however it will not refire jobs that were not ran before the application being restarted.
`var properties = new NameValueCollection
{
["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "QuartzRedisJobStoreCore.JobStore.RedisJobStore, QuartzRedisJobStoreCore.JobStore",
["quartz.jobStore.keyPrefix"] = "UnitJob",
["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json",
["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO",
["quartz.jobStore.dbNum"] = "1",
["quartz.jobStore.redisConfiguration"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("quartz_connection"),
["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "true",
["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "1",
[StdSchedulerFactory.PropertySchedulerInstanceName] = "QUARTZ_JOB",
};
        StdSchedulerFactory scheduleBuilder = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        IScheduler scheduler = scheduleBuilder.GetScheduler().Result;
        return scheduler;`

It to work. I cannot seem to figure it out.
